# Can I use different pages/routes in Nuxt.js depending on the server's domain?

Tags: nuxt.js

I would like to use one single Nuxt.js app for two different (sub-)domains, so depending on the (sub-)domain, I basically want to use two different routers.

In *Vue.js* this is easily done by exporting a different router object depending on the (sub-)domain:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
[...]
Vue.use(VueRouter);

const routerOne = new VueRouter({...});
const routerTwo = new VueRouter({...});

export default window.location.host.includes('subdomainOne') ? routerOne : routerTwo;
```

But *Nuxt.js* uses the `pages` directory for automatically creating the router.
But I would like `https://one.domain.de/overview` (as an example) to display a different view than `https://another.domain.de/overview`, i.e. *the pathnames of the URL should eventually be the same, but the pages/views being displayed should be completely different*. Is this possible at all?

This way I could easily use (partly) the same components for two different websites.